# Couldn't fit the data using NEURAL NETWORKS IN MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network, backpropagation

i have been trying the fit the data to a nonlinear model using neural networks in matlab. i have several sets of data. and my code is working fine for some data sets but not for all the data sets.

for some data sets i am able to fit with good regression coefficient.for some sets of data it is giving me a constant value of output (i.e: almost '0' regression coefficient).

this is the architecture of my neural network: Feedforward neural network with back propagation. no of hidden layers-1 no of neurons in a hidden layer -i am varying to see the result in each run

CAN ANYONE POINT OUT WHAT IS GOING WRONG IN MY CODE PLEASE???

```
  clear;
  %% to load data from excel file
  filename='dD.xlsx';
  x=xlsread(filename);
  p=x(:,2:12);
  t=x(:,1);
  inputs = p';
  targets = t';
  % rng(200,'v4');
  rng(0)
  %% Create a Fitting Network
  hiddenLayerSize = 5;
  net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize);
  %% Set up Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
  % net.divideFcn = 'dividetrain';  % No validation or test data
  net.divideParam.trainRatio = 100/100;
  net.divideParam.valRatio = 0/100;
  net.divideParam.testRatio = 0/100;
  net.trainFcn = 'trainbr';
  % net = configure(net,ptrans,tn);
  net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
  net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'purelin';
  %% Train the Network
  [net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
  tr.best_epoch;
  effective_param = tr.gamk;
  effective_no_of_parameters = effective_param(length(effective_param));
  wt_IL=net.IW{1,1};
  wt_HL= net.LW{2,1};
  bias_IL=net.b{1};
  bias_HL=net.b{2};
  %% Test the Network
  outputs = net(inputs);
  errors = gsubtract(outputs,targets);
  performance = perform(net,targets,outputs)
```

Comment: Well there's nothing obviously wrong with your code (I'm not saying there's obviously nothing wrong with your code!). If you say sometimes this code works and sometimes is doesn't then this makes me suspect the data, but you haven't really provided much detail about that.

Comment: Even i suspected the same about the data.The data has been taken from reported literature.i am able to fit the data using linear regression.it gives me lesser regression coefficient that is why i am trying to fit using Neural Networks.